# How to implement fullcalendar rails_admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, fullcalendar

Anyone has implemented fullcalendar with rails_admin?

I am not sure on how to proceed.

Comment: What do you mean under "fullcalendar"?

Comment: Sorry I meant implementing this gem. https://github.com/bokmann/fullcalendar-rails

Comment: Follow the documentation of gem

Answer (score 0):

You should first create a **custom action** through **rails_admin** where you can load **full calendar** have your calendar feature integrated in it.
please check below link
http://blog.paulrugelhiatt.com/ruby/rails/2014/10/27/rails-admin-custom-action-example.html

this will help